# trouble deploying reddit bot using heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bots, gunicorn, praw

I am very new and learning so please be gentle.
I've been trying to build a Reddit bot, hosted on GitHub and deployed using Heroku.
most issues I've run into I've been able to solve with google. I can't seem to find an answer to this.
my problems are in the logs of the deployment, which I now get are:

[CLI logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK0vE.jpg)

I've been trying every piece of advice I can but nothing seems to work.
What Am I doing wrong?

my files on GitHub are:

skb.py

```
import praw
import time

reddit = praw.Reddit(  
        user_agent="redacted" ,
        client_id="redacted",
        client_secret="redacted",
        username="redacted",
        password="redacted",)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("comedy")

joke_reply = ["CAUSE IT'S A JOKE OHH OHHHH OHHHHHHHHH"]

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
  #  print(submission.title)

    for comment in submission.comments:
        if hasattr(comment,"body"):
           comment_lower = comment.body.lower()
           if " a joke " in comment_lower:
                # print("------")
                 print(comment.body)
                 comment.reply(joke_reply)
                 time.sleep(66)
```

requirements.txt

```
  gunicorn==20.0.4
  praw==7.4.0
```

Procfile

```
web:gunicorn skb:app
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you provide a file structure, but for now,

### First make sure your script is working properly

Make sure the skb.py file is working.

### Next

Did you create an app.py? If you did, try linking it in the Procfile instead. `web: gunicorn app:app`

Next, do the above in a virutal environment.

### Logs

Seeing the logs, it appears to be a WSGI error, a Procfile error, so simplify your file structure and use guniform correctly. Refer to the docs [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the gunicorn info! What do you mean by file structure? I have it all uploaded to a github branch and deploy the branch in heroku, should I have it in a particular order?

Comment: No Not really, by file structure I meant how you arrange your files, something like this would be easier

https://i.imgur.com/vgUE0wq.png